# Table of contents page numbers not aligned to titles - InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I have created a table of contents with the

- Chapter title
- Page title and its corresponding number.

The numbers dont align however with the page number and I am not sure why. 3 should be aligned with "rational" and 7 should be aligned with "moodboard".
[image]

I have checked the leading of paragraph styles for the page title and the character style for the numbers and they are both on Auto.Neither are aligned to baseline grid as well. This is how I have set it up in the table of contents dialogue box.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell. Some comments: Is "The Brief" a *Chaper title* or a custom header you added or is it a *Chapter title*? It's probably just a naming thing, but the name *Page numbering* seems odd. Normally you would add titles/headers to this list. In the *Between Entry and Number* you have a whole list of characters. You should only need either an ordinary *Tab* character or a *Right Indent Tab*. Make sure none of the styles use *Baseline Shift*.

Comment: My first thought was Baseline Shift as well, but I don’t think that can be it – the first number is three lines above the page title, while with the second one it’s only two lines. Can you confirm that when you put the text cursor in the paragraph and arrow-key left and right, it does jump back and forth between the page title and the number, just like in a regular paragraph?

Comment: Hang on… do you have columns set up anywhere in the text frame here? This is the same TOC where you wanted to add line breaks before the numbers, right? Spam column settings may have something to do with this, though it’s hard to tell with Hidden Characters not shown. Could you update your first screenshot with one where Hidden Characters are shown?

Comment: @Wolff thank you I deleted all the characters in the before entry and number and that seems to have aligned the numbers to the title. I was changing the styles but it seems to add on a character each time instead of changing it not sure why.